# How to get Latitude/Longitude Values for a given address on Google App Engine Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-geocoder

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to get latitude/longitude values for a given address while working on google app engine java project. I see some classes like com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PostalAddress etc but could not use them to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call an external API, like the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a reverse geocoding, which deals when you pass the Lat/Long to retrieve an address by using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)